# How to solve the 'Attribute Error' in gym when colab is using GPU

Tags: google-colaboratory, openai-gym

here is my code:

```
!pip install box2d-py==2.3.8

import gym

env = gym.make('CarRacing-v0')
```

The err-msg is:

```
AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'CarRacing'
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piO4e.png)

But the same code is ok when colab is using the CPU environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
pip uninstall torch
```

and installing **cuda** version again

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

by the way try to use `CarRacing-v2` instead of `CarRacing-v0`

```
environment_name = "CarRacing-v2"
```